# converting `\oct` to `char` in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, backslash, qstring

I have a string like

```
QString result ("very much text\\374more Text");
```

and the `backslash-int-int-int` represents a char writen in an octal number. In this case it is a `ü`. I want to have the char `ü` instead of the backslash representation.

That's what I tried:

```
while (result.contains('\\'))
    if(result.length() > result.indexOf('\\') + 3)
    {
        bool success;
        int i (result.mid(result.indexOf('\\') + 1, 3).toInt(&success, 8));
        if (success)
        {
            //convert i to a string
            QString myStringOfBits ("\\u" + QString::number(i, 16));
            //QChar c = myStringOfBits.toUtf8();
            //qDebug() << c;
        }
    }
```

I'm a noob, I know that

Comment: When compiled, your text does not contain a `\\ ` character. Your compiler translates `\374` to the corresponding character

Comment: qDebug prints me `Pfad\ f\374r\ Ex-gesch\374tzte\ Dokumente`. I can replace `\ ` with a space but not the octal characters

Comment: Try [`QString::fromLatin1("very much text\374more Text")`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#fromLatin1)

Comment: that does not work very good. `\374` is displayed like no character in qDebug(). Second: I can't use `QString` variables in this case. sry

Comment: @chtz sry, forgot the double backslash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we have a result string:

```
QString result ("Ordner mit \\246 und \\214"); //its: "Ordner mit ö and Ö"
```

there is a solution with:

```
result = QString::fromLatin1("Ordner mit \\246 und \\214");
```

but you can't put in a variable. If you want to put in a variable you might use `(char)` to the `(decimal)octal` to its char equivalent:

```
while (result.contains("\\ ")) //replace spaces
    result = result.replace("\\ ", " ");
while (result.contains('\\')) //replace special characters
    if(result.length() > result.indexOf('\\') + 3)
    {
        bool success;
        int a (result.mid(result.indexOf('\\') + 1, 3).toInt(&success, 8)); //get the octal number as decimal
        //qDebug() << a; //print octal number
        //qDebug() << (char)a; //qDebug() will print "" because it can't handle special characters
        if (success)
        {
            result = result.mid(0, result.indexOf('\\')) +
                    (char)a + //replace the special character with the char equivalent
                    result.mid(result.indexOf('\\') + 4);
        }

    }
```

`qDebug()` won't display special characters but GUI does:

[image: Ordner mit \246 und \214]

so it works :) thanks to all of you

Answer (score 0):

all code in qt should be utf8 by default, so you could just put the ü in the string.

Comment: `\u00FC` would give me the character in utf8, doesn't it?